# Contribute Page with a Profile in Edit Mode - Not Create Mode?

Tags: profile, contribution-page, multi-record

using wordpress/CiviCRM 4.7.

I have a contribution page with a profile attached (under the profiles tab for the contribution admin page).  The profile contains custom fields that can have multiple entries.  When a user goes to this page, it is populating the contents with existing data from that user - I want to present an empty form for this.
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Please if anyone has a suggestion on how to resolve this?  I *really* need to fix this before I can let users access it because it is causing confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding `&cid=0` to the end of the donation page URL.  E.g. if your page URL is:

```
http://example.com/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1
```

Instead use:

```
http://example.com/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1&cid=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the user logged in? If so then it will auto populate with their details. I think you could override this but lets confirm how users are accessing the form first.

Comment: Yes, users are logged in - the configuration is as such - I have a custom group of fields which allow multiple records attached to individual records.  We are a dog registration association so this allows for multiple dogs to be registered.  When the user is logged in, they are given the option to register a new dog and it goes to a contribute page with a profile attached.  The profile page is populated, as you said likely because they are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain how to do this in WP. In Drupal you could use Webform. But the approach I would suggest, would be that you record the Dog as a Contact, and get some coding done to create the Relationship to the Owner. Then I would have the payment function as a Gift Membership or Soft Credit (waves hands around as not clear what you need) so that the payment is recorded on both Dog and Person.

Comment: Not really what I want.  It works for everything except that profile.  I do understand what you suggest, however.